# Forced Routing?

Tags: networking, routing

This is probably not the best place to ask this one, but hey...

I'm a user, sitting at my home PC, running Windows 7, on a simple ADSL link, via AT&T. Using Google Chrome, I'm attempting to browse to a certain site. The site does not respond. A traceroute shows that it is, indeed, unreachable.

I see the same result if I use Microsoft Internet Explorer.

However, if I browse the same site from my work PC, also running Windows 7 and Google Chrome, no problem at all. A traceroute from the work PC shows that both DNS providers (work and home) agree on name resolution of the site name (same dotted quads), but that's where the similarity ends. The system at work routes the browse completely differently.

Changing the DNS server on the home system has no effect.  The domain name resolution is correct.

I did manage to traceroute to one of the intermediate stops in the work traceroute, and the connectivity does exist to that point. I conjecture that the routing tables "closer" to my home PC are corrupted, poisoned, or otherwise NFG.

Is there anything I can do from User Land to force a more-correct routing?

Answer (score 1):

Switch home ISPs, or VPN into work (or to some other VPN provider), and make sure your VPN client is set to route all traffic via the VPN.